# issue hosting on firebase with React-Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I am trying to learn the basics of firebase and cloned a simple TODO project off of GitHub. Most has gone well and the site is live and the authentication is working, but the TODO functionality doesnt seem to be storing values once I hit enter. This is only true on firebase not in dev mode.

Can someone help me indicate where I've gone wrong or how to fix this small issue?

Here is the repo if it helps (nothing seems wrong with my react or redux code as it pass 100%):

https://github.com/donsalvadori/TODOM

Live demo:

https://todom-b01a6.firebaseapp.com/sign-in

My firebase.rules.json below:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "tasks": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I realize this post is light on code but I truly think this is more a firebase issue than my code since the tests which I cloned run 100% green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/donsalvadori/TODOM/blob/master/src/core/firebase/config.js

Currently reads:

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDznC6SgMJbq8s9ipNE_1OhB28_p00kVkk',
  authDomain: 'todom-b01a6.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://todom-b01a6.firebaseio.co',
  storageBucket: 'todom-b01a6.appspot.com'
};
```

Note the missing 'm' in the databaseURL.

Comment: can you further explain? The app is called in firebase todom hence the URL

Comment: also I know it's terrible practice to show API keys etc but this is just a throw away app to basically learn firebase

Comment: I feel so stupid must have accidently lopped off the last letter, thank you